# Yet Another Implementation of JPA Entity equals()/hashCode()

Tags: hibernate, jpa, entity, equals, hashcode

The history of the JPA entity `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods started a long ago. There is a ton of discussions, just google for the ["jpa equals hashcode"](https://www.google.com/search?q=jpa+equals+hashcode) and you'll find a brilliant [Vlad Mihalcea article](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-implement-equals-hashcode-and-tostring-with-jpa-and-hibernate/), an attempt to find gaps there by the [JPA Buddy team](https://jpa-buddy.com/blog/hopefully-the-final-article-about-equals-and-hashcode-for-jpa-entities-with-db-generated-ids/), a lot of posts here [at S/O](https://www.google.com/search?q=jpa+equals+hashcode+site%3Astackoverflow.com) and so on.

Of course, the topic is about a case when there is no business key to rely on and the only choice is to use an auto-generated sequence key.

First, I wonder

- why there is no official documentation from Hibernate
- and why Lombok doesn't step in with some fancy `@EqualsAndHashCodeOfSyntheticId` (instead there is another ton of articles explaining that applying the regular `@EqualsAndHashCode` to the entities is a really bad idea. Indeed, it is)

Then combining both Vlad's and JPA Buddy's solutions I am presenting yet another one for your evaluation

```
public abstract class AbstractSyntheticIdEntity {
    public abstract Long getId();

    @Override
    public final boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null) return false;

        if (effectiveClass(this) != effectiveClass(o)) return false;
        AbstractSyntheticIdEntity that = (AbstractSyntheticIdEntity) o;
        return getId() != null && getId().equals(that.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public final int hashCode() {
        return effectiveClass(this).hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(
                "%s(id=%d)",
                effectiveClass(this).getSimpleName(),
                getId()
        );
    }

    private static Class<?> effectiveClass(Object obj) {
        return obj instanceof HibernateProxy
                ? ((HibernateProxy) obj).getHibernateLazyInitializer().getPersistentClass()
                : obj.getClass();
    }
}
```

Cons:

- it is Hibernate specific (I guess it is not a big issue, saying JPA we usually mean Hibernate)
- uses inheritance
- assumes that the `id` is `Long`, if you're mixing both `Long` and `Integer` for ids it could be easily parameterized

Pros:

- there is no need to put the very same `equals()` and `hashCode()` everywhere, just extend your entity from it
- it passes Vlad's [IdEqualityTest](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/high-performance-java-persistence/blob/master/core/src/test/java/com/vladmihalcea/hpjp/hibernate/equality/IdEqualityTest.java) (before jumping into the discussion, I kindly ask you to evalute your hypotesis against it) meaning that different entity states, proxies, references, sets and so on are taken into consideration
- a base `toString` implementation is not mandatory and is a bonus. The entity could overwrite it of course (avoid implicit extra loading though!)

Any feedback is highly appreciated.

P.S.

If the cons are an impediment for you, I guess there is nothing better rather then using Vlad's solution and put this snippet for **every** entity

```
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof CLASS_NAME)) return false;
        CLASS_NAME that = (CLASS_NAME) o;
        return id != null && id.equals(that.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return getClass().hashCode();
    }
```

Comment: I have never used `equals/hashCode` for entities in PROD for a long time and many applications.

Comment: @v.ladynev That's a common approach unfortunately. Let me guess, you aren't using Sets, Maps, References, don't compare entities in the way `entity1.equals(entity2)` or `entities.contains(someEntity)`, right? Well, if you don't invoke `equals()` implicitly or explicitly you could not to implement it. I would still to suggest to read articles mentioned above.

Comment: Thank you @AndriySlobodyanyk! We stand upon the real live cases that we massively see. When you say "should be implemented for EVERY entity" you introduce another convention, that must be checked every time. So, you have a few options. To believe that everybody will remember the convention OR Setup checkstyle OR Develop your own way of E/НС control. However, the most common way is to introduce the base entity. We see such an approach in 9 of 10 cases. Aslo we see instanceof used in the MappedSuperclasses a lot.

Comment: @aleksey.stukalov The problem seems to be that any entity has already had the implementation of the `equals()/hashCode()` from the `Object` class. So any solution (Vlad's, yours, someone else) might be forgotten unless it is checked with some code analysis tool. What do you think about the BaseEntity (well, exteding of it might be also forgotten though)?

Comment: In fact the Object's one performs better than the other. At least it doesn't lead to an ambiguous result within a single transaction.

Comment: This is opinion based so not great for stack overflow. IMO equals/hashcode are down right bad - they are misused as test helper methods that verify the data is exactly the same. Java's default implementation is better than 90% of the generic impls I've seen, especially for sets where if anything in the entity changes, the previous hashcode differs from the new one; a huge problem when a new entity is assigned an ID after persist (or after synchronization to the DB if using identity). Don't implement it unless you have specific requirements.

Comment: @Chris Assigning an ID after persist is a natural Hibernate behaviour (especially doing by cascades). So we need the equals/hashCode implementations that do not break Set's contacts and other things

Comment: Id modification doesn't break or even affect Java's object equals/hashcode implementation at all - it breaks common user implementations. hashcode on an object should never change. That you want two sets of data that are different instances to return the same hashcode and be treated as one is a separate problem, and you should look at why you really need that. Is merge returning a different instance really a problem for your application that you need to resolve it with this, or can you just not keep a handle on what was passed in and replace it in sets/maps with what is passed back?